# how to disable google analytics on localhost

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, google-analytics

I use this for google analytics,

```
<noscript>
<iframe src="//www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-KCQGLT" height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
```

and this

```
<script>(function(w, d, s, l, i) {
w[l] = w[l] || [];
w[l].push({
    'gtm.start': new Date().getTime(),
    event: 'gtm.js'
});
var f = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
    j = d.createElement(s),
    dl = l != 'dataLayer' ? '&l=' + l : '';
j.async = true;
j.src =
    '//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=' + i + dl;
f.parentNode.insertBefore(j, f);})(window, document, 'script', 'dataLayer', 'GTM-KCQGLT');</script>
```

Can I disable this script when I run this code in localhost?

Comment: just comment it

Comment: Comment it or `if(/localhost/.test(window.location.hostname)) return`

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Use below code.

```
<script>
var host = window.location.hostname;
if(host != "localhost")
{
    // your google analytic code here
}
</script>
```

Comment: By far the best comment. Simple and gets the job done. Thanks,

Answer (score 24):

As described [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/user-opt-out), this is the correct way to prevent further events being sent to google analytics, even after `ga(...)` has been initialized:

```
if (admin || localhost) { // disable GA:
  window['ga-disable-UA-XXXXX-Y'] = true; // enter your tracking ID
}
```

Now any further calls to `ga(...)` will have no effect.

Quoting the docs:

> The analytics.js library includes a window property that, when set to true, disables analytics.js from sending data to Google Analytics. When Google Analytics attempts to set a cookie or send data back to the Google Analytics servers, it will check whether this property is set to true. If it is, no action will be taken.
>
> To disable tracking, set the following window property to true:
>
> `window['ga-disable-UA-XXXXX-Y'] = true;`
>
> Where the value UA-XXXXX-Y corresponds to the property ID on which you would like to disable tracking.

Comment: Please don't add the [same answer to multiple questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104227/is-it-acceptable-to-add-a-duplicate-answer-to-several-questions). Answer the best one and flag the rest as duplicates, once you earn enough reputation. If it is not a duplicate, tailor the post to the question and flag for undeletion.

Comment: `gtag.js` documentation: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/user-opt-out

Comment: `ga4` document : https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ga4/disable-analytics

Comment: This should be the correct answer since it correctly references the literature and code directly from google's documentation.

Answer (score 3):

go to Analytics Settings, edit your site, and +Add Filter to define a filter that excludes your IP address.

Comment: This doesn't stop the analytics executing. It only "filters" out any data on the server that originated from 'localhost'.